# Add array values to HTML sidebar from Google Sheet (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet that contains a list of hotel names. The hotel names are listed in cells D25-D57 (excluding D37-38, 44-45, 51-52).

I've written a script to generate a sidebar and the idea is that the sidebar will list all the hotels listed in the spreadsheet. Here is my HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    .sortableItem {
      height: 50px;
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding-top: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
      background-color: #e7f0fe;
      color: gray;
      margin: 3px;
    }

    .sortableItem:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #sortable {
      float: left;
    }

    #times {
      float: left;
    }

    .day {
      background-color: #4285f4;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#sortable").sortable();
    });

    $(".sortable").sortable({
      cancel: ".disable-sort-item"
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="sortable">
    <div class="sortableItem day">Monday</div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result1"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result2"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result3"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result4"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result5"></div>

    <div class="sortableItem day">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result6"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result7"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result8"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result9"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result10"></div>

    <div class="sortableItem day">Wednesday</div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result11"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result12">Hotel 2</div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result13">Hotel 3</div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result14">Hotel 4</div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result15">Hotel 5</div>

    <div class="sortableItem day">Thursday</div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result16"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result17"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result18"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result19"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result20"></div>

    <div class="sortableItem day">Friday</div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result21"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result22"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result23"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result24"></div>
    <div class="sortableItem" id="result25"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The hotel names should go into the divs with id "result1, 2" etc.

In my GS file I have the following:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Menu')
    .addItem('Sort meeting order', 'openSortableSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function openSortableSidebar(data) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sortable');
  var sidebar_html = html.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(sidebar_html);
}

var hotelName = "";
var targetCells = [
  "D25",
  "D26",
  "D27",
  "D28",
  "D29",
  "D32",
  "D33",
  "D34",
  "D35",
  "D36",
  "D39",
  "D40",
  "D41",
  "D42",
  "D43",
  "D46",
  "D47",
  "D48",
  "D49",
  "D50",
  "D51",
  "D52",
  "D53",
  "D54",
  "D55"
];

function findHotel() {
  var hotelNames = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < targetCells.length; i++) {
    hotelName = sheet.getRange(targetCells[i]).getValue();
    hotelNames.push(hotelName);
    return hotelNames;
  }
}
```

So I have the target cells (i.e. those containing the hotel names in my spreadsheet) as an array and my for loop is working successfully in that it is pushing all the hotel names in those cells through to the array. My problem is with communicating this server side.

So in my HTML file I had worked out how to push one value into the first 'result' div and managed to write a for loop pushing the same value through to all the divs. But I cannot seem to push the array through successfully. This is what I have tried:

```
<script>  
  var idArray = ["result1", "result2", "result3"]

  function addHotel(hotelNames){
    for(var i=0; i<idArray.length +1; i++){
      $('#result' + i).text(hotelNames[i]);
    }
  }; 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addHotel).findHotel();
</script>
```

I know it's clearly not that simple but I am stuck on this. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated :)

PS: my id array would obviously be longer and go up to 25 usually...

Comment: I have 2 questions for your situation. 1. Are you required to use ``var targetCells = ["D25", "D26",,,]``? If it uses ``sheet.getRange("D25:D55").getValues()``, the values of "D25:D55" can be retrieved. 2. Are you required to use ``var idArray = ["result1", "result2", "result3"]``? For example, if it uses ``var idArray = 25``, the script can be more simple. I would like to modify your script after I got your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 1- the first array I think needs to be like this simply because there are some cells within that column I need to ignore (but happy to find a better way if you have one ;) ) 2- I'm not attached to the 'result1' ids so happy for you to amend these

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I would like to modify using ``sheet.getRange("D25:D55").getValues()`` and ``var idArray = 25``. If you want to modify other parts, please tell me.

Comment: go for it that's fine

Comment: I posted my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- For GAS, modified `var targetCells = ["D25", "D26",,,]` to "D25:D55".
- For Javascript, modified `var idArray = ["result1", "result2", "result3"]` to `var idArray = 25`.

#### Modified script

GAS :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .createMenu('Menu')
  .addItem('Sort meeting order', 'openSortableSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function openSortableSidebar(data) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sortable');
  var sidebar_html = html.evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(sidebar_html);
}

// This function was modified
function findHotel() {
  var rangeData = ["D25:D29", "D32:D36", "D39:D43", "D46:D51", "D53:D57"];
  var ranges = sheet.getRangeList(rangeData).getRanges();
  var values = ranges.map(function(e){return e.getValues().map(function(e){return e[0]})});
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], values);
}
```

Javascript :

```
<script> 
  var idArray = 25; // Modified

  function addHotel(hotelNames){
    for(var i=0; i<idArray; i++){ // Modified
      $('#result' + (i + 1)).text(hotelNames[i]); // Modified
    }
  };

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addHotel).findHotel();
</script>
```

#### Note :

- HTML is not modified.
- In this modified script, please set the ranges you want as follows.

  - `var rangeData = ["D25:D29", "D32:D36", "D39:D43", "D46:D51", "D53:D57"];`.

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks so much - this is almost perfect ! The only issue I have is as I thought, with the array referring to the cells on the spreadsheet. Because there are cells I need to ignore, it's not quite working. I tried this: return sheet.getRange("D25:D29, D32:D36, D39:D43, D46:D51, D53:D57").getValues().map(function(e){return e[0]}); ... but that didn't work at all :/

Comment: @DaveB1 I'm sorry for the inconvenience. You want to use the values retrieved by the various ranges. For this situation, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? When you use various ranges, please set the ranges you want like ``var rangeData = ["D25:D29", "D32:D36", "D39:D43", "D46:D51", "D53:D57"];``.  If I misunderstand your comment, please tell me.

Comment: absolutely awesome! Not sure I follow everything you've done but will dig through it tomorrow to see if I can understand the logic a bit more. Thanks a million

Comment: on this one I need a little more input. With the result that i get from return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], values); I need to concatenate this value with the values in column G (same rows as the array with column D). So in col D I have names of hotels and in G I have the addresses. Essentially I need to concatenate these and pull the result through to the HTML service. The problem being, when user re-orders the elements in the sidebar and submits, I need a way of getting the address to stick with the hotel name - does that make sense?!

Comment: @DaveB1 I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't understand what you want to do. So I cannot image the vision. Can I ask you about the detail information? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So imagine my google sheet has hotel names listed from D25:D57 and hotel addresses in H25:H57. What we have so far is that the user opens the sidebar and the hotel names are displayed. The user can then drag these names and drop them to change the order and when they click submit, the hotel names on the google sheet change position to match the new order. But I need the addresses to change position as well! Otherwise the wrong address is assigned to the hotel

Comment: There was another thread you were helping me in with this project. So I realised to pull the new order through from the HTML service to tag server side (google sheet) I needed a name attribute so I created a load of text boxes which pick up the new order if the hotel names and I use the name values of these inputs to pull through to the server. But these contain only the hotel name. I wondered if I could concatenate this with the address I could maybe separate them again into the respective cells in the google sheet

Comment: @DaveB1 Thank you for your quick reply. I cannot understand the vision of what you want yet. I'm really sorry. So can you post it including the sample input and output you want as a new question? When I can get the vision, I think that I can think of your solution. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill again.

Comment: it's not your English it's my coding :) !!!! Started this project but it's escalated into something a bit too complex! I re-posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356089/pulling-multiple-linked-data-from-html-service-to-server-side-google-apps-scrip

Comment: @DaveB1 Thank you for replying and posting the question including the detail information. I would like to check it.